# lottie - toggle switch

Tags: android, json

Estou tentando configurar um *toggle* switch no android studio usando a documentação do lottie.
Consegui, mas esta dando um erro, preciso de uma ajudinha galera.

```
final boolean[] oontrole = {false};
        final LottieAnimationView animationView = (LottieAnimationView) findViewById(R.id.animation_view);

    animationView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(oontrole[0]) {
                animationView.setAnimation("androidDesliga.json");//animação botao desligando
                animationView.playAnimation();
                oontrole[0] = false;
            } else {
                animationView.setAnimation("androidLiga.json");//animação botao ligando
                animationView.playAnimation();
                oontrole[0] = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Seja mais específico, qual é o erro gerado?